# Azure B2B gives an error for some emails

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-connect, azure-ad-b2b

I've developed a software that automates **Azure B2B invitation process**. All works well. But we found that for some email addresses we receive **400 Bad Request** response message when making *invitation call to Azure*.

Error message:

```
The object either is sourced from an on prem directory or is undergoing migration
```

Can't find any good info explains how I can fix this problem. And what is a reason of the problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using Azure AD Connect to sync your on-premise AD with Azure AD.

**Cause:** The Email you tried to invited had been in your on-premise AD and under sync. With this suituation, you cannot invite this kind user with same Email as the on-premise user's.

**Solution:**

1. Sync this user to Azure AD and make the user to be a member in AAD.
2. Stop sync or after sync failed, invite this user to your AAD.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: How I can sync this user to my Azure AD? I thought that I need to invite this user first..

Comment: Hi @Vnuuk . Since you're using AAD connect, you can sync this user to AAD as a member. But you can also use powershell`Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial` to sync and waite Waited until `(Get-ADSyncScheduler).SyncCycleInProgress` go back to `False`. Then you can invite the user to be a guest.

Comment: Can I use Graph API to sync user to AAD as a member? Or maybe there is a way to invite user not as a guest but as a member?